# Add custom s4-ribbonrow panel in html site page in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, share, sitepages, follow

I have a doubt on SharePoint Site Pages which is customized entirely by removing all asp:Content and replaced with html. The entire page is now composed of html5 tags. Now I need to bring back the Share and Follow buttons that exist in s4-ribbon row. Is there anyway I could add it to the existing page? Please help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`<link href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="init.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />`

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="MicrosoftAjax.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />`

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sp.core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />`

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sp.runtime.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />`

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sp.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />`

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sp.ui.dialog.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />`

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />`

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />`

```
`   function OpenShareDialog() {
    alert('hr');

      var options =
      {
          url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/aclinv.aspx?forSharing=1&mbypass=1&IsDlg=1",
          dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, dialogClosedCallback)    
       };

     SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

}

function dialogClosedCallback(result, target) 
{
    alert('hi');      
}
```

`

These dependencies will help us achieve the lost custom functionalities. Hope someday it will help someone.

Inside HTML body: